# Intel Hex - Converting 03 record type to 05 and vice versa

Tags: hex, intel

I am trying to write an [Intex HEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) parser. It seems that there are two styles for extended addresses (allowing you to address memory larger than 64 kB), and that these two styles shouldn't be mixed in the same file:

- Segment Addressing
- Linear Addressing

I want to write a parser that will take Intel HEX in any of the above two styles, and output in any of the above styles.

I've got a handle on all the record types except for `03` (*Start Segment Address*) and `05` (*Start Linear Address*). My assumption, based on the wikipedia article is that for the following record of type `03` (ignore dashes - just to aid annotation):

```
:04-0000-03-00003800-C1
|_1|___2|_3|_______4|_5|
```

where:

```
1 - 04 -> byte count
2 - 0000 -> address
3 - 03 -> record type (Start Segment Address)
4 - 00003800 -> data
5 - C1 -> checksum
```

If I were to convert this into a `05` type record type, would be:

```
:0400000500003800BF
```

Where I just simply take the `IP` address (last 2 data bytes) of the `03` record and set that to the data field for the `05` type, padded with `0000`; completely ignoring the first 2 bytes of the data section of the `03` record (which in this example is `0000`).

Is this correct? Am I making any faulty assumptions / missing the point entirely?